# Is there an error in an Effective JavaScript example about using arguments object to create variadic functions?

Tags: javascript

There is an example in Effective JavaScript that seems to me to be incorrect. It is about "using *arguments* to create variadic functions".
From the book:

> a good rule of thumb is that whenever you provide a variable-arity function for convenience, you should also provide a fixed-arty version that takes an explicit array

So here is the example for calculating an average of values:

Fixed-arity version:

```
function averageOfArrays(a) {
    for (var i = 0, sum = 0, n = a.length; i < n; i++) {
        sum += a[i];
    }
    return sum / n;
}
```

Variadic version:

```
function average() {
    for (var i = 0, sum = 0, n = arguments.length; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arguments[i];
    }
    return sum / n;
}
```

Variadic version as wrapper that delegates to the fixed-arity version:

```
function average() {
    return averageOfArray(arguments);
}
```

This last version is supposed to be convenient because the user can input either a list of values or a single argument that is an array of values. I don't see how this would work for an array of values. And when I call

```
average([1,2,3])
```

I get NaN.

This wrapper version is wrong, right? If so the book is wrong on this example and I need no further explanation.

Comment: “This last version is supposed to be convenient because the user can input either a list of values or a single argument that is an array of values.” According to…?

Comment: This last version is only supposed to accept a list of values, not _single argument that is an array of values_. So there is no error.

Comment: `average(1,2,3)` *and* `average(1)`; not `average([1,2,3])`

Comment: "Variadic functions make for flexible interfaces; different clients can call them with different numbers of arguments. But by themselves, they lose a bit of convenience: if consumers want to call them with a computed array of arguments, they have to use the apply method described in Item 21." And then the author proceeds to solve this inconvenience by defining the wrapper function "average".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As other commenters have indicated, the idea is not that the function

```
function average() {
    return averageOfArray(arguments);
}
```

covers both the array and the variadic case. As you observed, that function does not work with an array argument, and it is not intended to.

Instead, the idea is that you write the fixed-arity function (`averageOfArray`), and then you get a variadic function (`average`) basically "for free" (as implemented above).

Then users of your library will call either `average(1, 2, 3)` or `averageOfArray([1, 2, 3])` as suits their fancy, but it is not intended that users will be able to call `average([1, 2, 3])`.

Your confusion is justified, because the book does get it slightly mixed up, specifically in this passage: "A good rule of thumb is that whenever you provide a variable-arity function for convenience, you should also provide a fixed-arity version that takes an explicit array. This`[*see below]` is usually easy to provide, because you can typically implement the variadic function as a small wrapper that delegates to the fixed-arity version."

The "this" highlighted above seems to be referring to a *fixed*-arity function; in other words, it says that you get the fixed-arity version "for free" from the variable-arity function. In fact, however, as the above example illustrates and as the second sentence in the above quotation accurately describes, the truth is precisely the opposite. You get the variable-arity version "for free" after implementing the fixed-arity version.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your understanding of what the book means is a bit off.  Instead, the book offers two separate versions, one that takes a single argument as an array and another version that accepts a list of numeric arguments.

What would be even better is a single version that adapts to the arguments passed to it so you can have one function that accepts either which is one of the strengths of Javascript.  Here's a version that accepts one or more arguments that can be single values or arrays:

```
function average() {
    var item, sum = 0, cnt = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        item = arguments[i];
        if (Array.isArray(item)) {
            item.forEach(function(value) {
                sum += value;
                cnt++;
            });
        } else {
            sum += item;
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    return cnt === 0 ? 0 : sum / cnt;
}
```

This can then be used in any of these ways:

```
average(1, 2, 3)
average([1, 2, 3])
average([1, 2], 3)

var data1 = [1, 2, 3]
var data2 = [4, 5, 6];
average(data1, data2, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the book "Effective Javascript", but the example seems correct to me.

I think what this is getting at is that you can use `average` with *variadic* arguments:

So, now you can do this:

```
average(1,2,3);
```

or this:

```
average(1);
```

and everything still works as expected.

If the book was trying to say that you could do this:

```
average([1,2,3]);
```

or this:

```
average([1]);
```

There would be no reason to use a *variadic* function because the parameter is *always* and single array.

Because it is always a single array, the original `averageOfArray` already works for this function signature.